# How to create standard SQL tables in bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, legacy-sql

I just checked the web UI, to create an empty table all the data types exposed are legacy SQL data types. I then checked out `bq mk` and I cannot see any option to set the standard SQL flag.

Even weird thing is if I create a table using standard SQL data types,

```
bq mk --schema name:string,value:int64 -t test.newtable5
Table 'oandmpoc:test.newtable5' successfully created.
```

It creates a table with `value  INTEGER`, I'll dig around later to see how ARRAY and STRUCT data types behave. Is there anything obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Did you check out the DDL documentation? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery does not store tables differently for legacy SQL versus standard SQL. `INTEGER` is the legacy SQL alias for the `INT64` type. Likewise, `RECORD` is an alias for `STRUCT`. You'll notice that the [legacy SQL data types reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/data-types) has entries for `DATE`, `TIME`, and `DATETIME` even though these are most useful from standard SQL.

More info about about which legacy SQL types map to which standard SQL types is available on the [migrating from legacy SQL documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#type_differences).

Comment: Thanks - but we have a problem when using with Tableau. It sends STRUCT data types in an ARRAY with "." (dot) notation when requesting for metadata. But those names cannot be used in further queries. I'm not sure why BQ is doing it when using standard SQL. http://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/google-bigquery-service-was-unable-to-compile-the-query-unrecognized-name

Comment: What's the schema look like and what are you trying to do in Tableau? That could probably be another question.